# Determining Priority of Programs' Handling Keyboard Input

Tags: linux, keyboard-events, gnu-screen

When I run vim in a terminal screen buffer under the gnu screen terminal multiplexer, the effect of Cntrl-A is initiation a screen binding. But when I run vim in a terminal screen buffer without gnu screen, the effect of Cntrl-A is vim incrementing the number under the cursor. What is giving screen priority over vim in this case? Can I override or customize this priority scheme?

Answer (score 1):

Ctrl-A is GNU Screen's default escape character, also called the command character; it precedes every screen command.  You can change it to something else using a command-line switch (-e xy) when you run screen or within screen using ctrl-a : escape xy.  In both cases x is the new escape character, for example ^B, and y is the key to send that escape character to the program in the window.  Or you can put the "escape" command in your .screenrc initialization file.  The default is -e ^Aa meaning you can send a ctrl-A to vi by typing ctrl-a followed by "a".

This is explained in the GNU Screen manual in the sections on [Invoking Screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/html_node/Invoking-Screen.html#Invoking-Screen) and [Command Character](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/html_node/Command-Character.html#Command-Character).

Comment: Your comment on how to resolve the problematic use case I raised is useful. My question about the source of screen's keyboard priority over vim remains.

Comment: That's just the way it works?  Screen passes all keyboard input to vim except the escape char (Ctrl-a by default), which it recognizes as a command to screen itself.